# Is there a way in R to extract data from a website using Microsoft Power BI

Tags: r, web-scraping, powerbi, rvest, rselenium

I am working on a project related to COVID travel restrictions and want to use data from
https://migration.iom.int/, in particular the data on country travel restriction (press on the tab on the bottom right once the page has loaded). My usual rvest approach to web scraping does not seem to work for the site. Any suggestions on possible ways to extract data from the site?

Comment: Where is data. Provide the proper link or screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The data is from JS files like this one: https://migration.iom.int/sites/all/themes/fmp/pages/heatmap/js/heatmap_2020-07-23.js